# What do the words 'Hinei Makom Iti' mean if Makom is also a title for G-d?

Tags: commentaries, parashat-ki-tisa

In Shemot 33:21 HaShem utters the words: 'הִנֵּה מָקוֹם אִתִּי'. I noticed HaShem uses the word 'makom', which reminded me of another teaching in which the word Makom is considered to be some sort of title for G-d. For example mitzvot such as shabat and kashrut, which do not directly involve other people, are known as *mitzvot bein adam v'makom*, 'mitzvot between people and G-d'.  A traditional way of comforting mourners is to say *HaMakom yenachem otcha*, 'May The Place (G-d) comfort you'.

So here's my question: If the word Makom is often taken to mean or refer to G-d, then what is HaShem saying here to Moshe?

Comment: See Seder Yonat Elem at beginning

Comment: @kouty any link?, possibility to post as an answer or could you refer me to any translation?

Answer (score 2):

Although מָקוֹם is used a descriptor for Hashem according to the statement of Chazal (see [here](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%94%D7%99%D7%9D_(%D7%99%D7%94%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA)#cite_note-41))

> שהוא מקום לעולם ואין העולם מקום לו
>
> That He is the place of the world and the world is not His place.
>
> בראשית רבה סח; יומא, פרק ח', משנה ט'; ברכות, דף ט"ז, עמוד ב

this does not take the word  מָקוֹם out of its original meaning.

Comment: Would this concept apply to *Baruch Hashem mimkomo*? I'm not completely understanding the above phrase and the concept of "defining" a specific place for G-d esp. if we believe that G-d has no physical form.

Comment: @DanF You make a good point. IMHO wherever "mokom" is used regarding Hashem, we cannot interpret it in a physical way and must use whatever other interpretations Chazal give us.